# Tiva ADC Sequencer with different step sources

Tags: c, arm, embedded, cortex-m

I'm trying to measure some ADC channels with the same sequencer. I took a base on the Chapter 5 of [Texas Tiva's ARM Cortex-M4 Workshop](http://software-dl.ti.com/trainingTTO/trainingTTO_public_sw/GSW-TM4C123G-LaunchPad/TM4C123G_LaunchPad_Workshop_Workbook.pdf). So, my (interrupted) original code is working perfectly:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "inc/hw_ints.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/adc.h"
#include "driverlib/interrupt.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/pin_map.h"

uint32_t ui32ADC0Value[4];

volatile uint32_t ui32TempAvg;
volatile uint32_t ui32TempValueC;

int main(void) {

    SysCtlClockSet(
    SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_SYSDIV_5);

    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_ADC0);
    SysCtlPeripheralReset(SYSCTL_PERIPH_ADC0);

    ADCSequenceDisable(ADC0_BASE, 1);
    ADCSequenceConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 1, ADC_TRIGGER_PROCESSOR, 0);

    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOD);
    GPIOPinTypeADC(GPIO_PORTD_BASE,
    GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1 | GPIO_PIN_2);

    ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 1, 0, ADC_CTL_TS);
    ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 1, 1, ADC_CTL_TS);
    ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 1, 2, ADC_CTL_TS);
    ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 1, 3,
    ADC_CTL_TS | ADC_CTL_IE | ADC_CTL_END);

    IntEnable(INT_ADC0SS1);
    ADCIntEnable(ADC0_BASE, 1);
    ADCSequenceEnable(ADC0_BASE, 1);

    IntMasterEnable();

    while (1) {
        ADCProcessorTrigger(ADC0_BASE, 1);
    }

}

void ISRHandler(void) {

    while (!ADCIntStatus(ADC0_BASE, 1, false)){};

    ADCIntClear(ADC0_BASE, 1);
    ADCSequenceDataGet(ADC0_BASE, 1, ui32ADC0Value);

    ui32TempAvg = ui32ADC0Value[3];

    ui32TempValueC = (1475 - ((2475 * ui32TempAvg)) / 4096) / 10;

}
```

However if I change this part

```
ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 1, 0, ADC_CTL_TS);
ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 1, 1, ADC_CTL_TS);
ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 1, 2, ADC_CTL_TS);
ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 1, 3,
        ADC_CTL_TS | ADC_CTL_IE | ADC_CTL_END);
```

by this part (so the steps 0 to 2 read other channels, instead of ADC_CTL_TS), where my analog pin channels are *grounded* (so the measurement would read near zero):

```
ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 1, 0, ADC_CTL_CH7);
ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 1, 1, ADC_CTL_CH6);
ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 1, 2, ADC_CTL_CH5);
ADCSequenceStepConfigure(ADC0_BASE, 1, 3,
        ADC_CTL_TS | ADC_CTL_IE | ADC_CTL_END);
```

the step 3 (where I measure ADC_CTL_TS) goes crazy, ranging values totally incoherent. Also, looking into debug, the measurement of TS looks like "walking" throught the other steps, because when 3 of them are near 0, the other "moving one" is far bigger. It looks like a temporal misalignment.

Why, and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tiva C's ADC sequencer is reading the samples into a dedicated FIFO, which has different depth for different sequencers. In your case (SS1) the FIFO depth is 4. Now let's look how you trigger the ADC. You are running the `ADCProcessorTrigger` in your main loop, without any delay or synchronization with the reading of the ADC, even without checking the previous conversion is done. So, as the samples are incoming, they are constantly "pushing out" the previous samples from the FIFO, and the FIFO easily getting out of sync (e.g. the sample from channel `i` will be displaced to some other place in the FIFO, or even pushed out.). So the correct way would be to trigger the conversion AFTER the data from the FIFO is read completely, and it is done in the interrupt. So I recommend putting `ADCProcessorTrigger` part near the end of the interrupt handler (and an initial trigger in `main`).

Comment: And in the case where I use the ADC_TRIGGER_ALWAYS, without the processor trigger, where should I fix it?

Comment: I have never worked with this mode, and believe it is not very useful for this way of operation. IMO it  can suffice for single channel sampling, or DMA operation (or if you really confident with your timings). Actually, I believe it will work in your case.